# Comparing data values from mySQL (WPF - C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I am attempting to learn .WPF and I've already encountered snag.
I'm trying to take 2 user input strings, via text-boxes, and compare both strings to values
retrieved from a mySQL database.

findUserFromDB function below: ( this is supposed to retrieve and compare the user values )

```
    public static void findUserFromDB(string user, string pass)
    {
        List<User> users = new List<User> { };
        MySqlDataReader reader = null;
        bool userFound = false;
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();

        try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            //Sets command text and connection database
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format("Select * From users");
            cmd.Connection = myConn;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                User forUser = new User
                {
                    sName = reader.GetString("Forename").Trim(),
                    sPass = reader.GetString("Password").Trim(),
                };
                users.Add(forUser);

            }
            if (userFound == false)
            {
                MessageBoxResult msg = MessageBox.Show(main, "Username or Password" +
                    " not recognised.", "Login failed", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < user.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (users[i].sName == user && users[i].sPass == pass)
                {
                    Menu m = new Menu();
                    string message = "Welcome back " + user + ".";
                    MessageBoxResult msg = MessageBox.Show(main, message,
                        "Login successful", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                    m.Show();
                    main.Close();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close(); //Close the reader
            }
            if (myConn != null)
            {
                myConn.Close(); //ensure you close the connection
            }
        }
```

looking at it now I realise that I should be retrieving the data and then closing the DB, before comparing the values...

My questions:
What am I doing wrong?
As soon as I press the button to login nothing happens.

Comment: 1 note here - why are you getting ALL of the users from the DB and compare them locally? That's inappropriate. Add `where` condition to your sql command and retrieve only 1 matching row. Also - I don't think user logins and passwords should be ever trimmed.

Comment: I realize the code posted isn't all of your code, but what you have posted never sets `userFound` to true.  Also, Tarec's suggestion to add a `WHERE` clause to your SQL so you restrict the data returned to the user you're interested in is a very good idea & you should take his advice.

Comment: After posting this I had changed those things in the code before managing to resolve the issue. It now draws a single row compares it and flags a true if necessary. the trim is gone and passwords are encrypted...

Comment: This is my code by the way. I was only test ng with 2 columns, pass and username, so there was no need for a where clause. I have however altered the while (reader.Read ()) to read until it finds the  correct user information.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.

Was referencing the wrong Database ^^,
God I feel stupid...